# WELD-001318 Cannot resolve an ambiguous dependency between . . . in GlassFish 4

Tags: java, maven, glassfish

I have lost mainly the whole morning trying to understand what is wrong with my application without having been successfull.

I have found similar questions here but I could not find an answer to my problem.

first here the List of errors GlassFish 4 ist showing wenn I run my application:

> SEVERE:   Critical error during deployment: 
> org.jboss.weld.exceptions.AmbiguousResolutionException: WELD-001318 Cannot resolve an ambiguous dependency between [Managed Bean [class com.sun.faces.flow.FlowDiscoveryCDIHelper] with qualifiers [@Default @Named @Any], Managed Bean [class **com.sun.faces.flow.FlowDiscoveryCDIHelper] with qualifiers [@Default @Named @Any]]**
>     at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.resolve(BeanManagerImpl.java:1130)
>     at org.jboss.weld.el.AbstractWeldELResolver.lookup(AbstractWeldELResolver.java:107)
>     at org.jboss.weld.el.AbstractWeldELResolver.getValue(AbstractWeldELResolver.java:96)
>     at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:188)
>     at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
>     at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
>     at com.sun.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:116)
>     at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:226)
>     at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
>     at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationAssociate$PostConstructApplicationListener.loadFlows(ApplicationAssociate.java:324)
>     at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationAssociate$PostConstructApplicationListener.processEvent(ApplicationAssociate.java:300)
>     at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.processListener(SystemEvent.java:108)
>     at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.processListeners(ApplicationImpl.java:2187)
>     at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.invokeListenersFor(ApplicationImpl.java:2163)
>     at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:296)
>     at javax.faces.application.ApplicationWrapper.publishEvent(ApplicationWrapper.java:739)
>     at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.publishPostConfigEvent(ConfigManager.java:680)
>     at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:253)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:5362)
>     at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.contextListenerStart(WebModule.java:743)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5898)
>     at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:691)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1041)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:1024)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:747)
>     at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2291)
>     at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1937)
>     at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:139)
>     at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
>     at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:291)
>     at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:352)
>     at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:497)
>     at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
>     at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
>     at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:527)
>     at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:523)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)
>     at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:522)
>     at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:546)
>     at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1423)
>     at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1500(CommandRunnerImpl.java:108)
>     at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1761)
>     at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1674)
>     at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
>     at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
>     at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandler.service(StaticHttpHandler.java:297)
>     at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:246)
>     at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
>     at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
>     at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
>     at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
>     at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
>     at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
>     at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
>     at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
>     at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
>     at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
>     at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
>     at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
>     at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
>     at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
>     at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
>     at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
>
> SEVERE:   Startup of context /movieplex7 failed due to previous errors
> SEVERE:   Exception during cleanup after start failed

The Problem is that I do not have in my Application any com.sun.faces.flow.FlowDiscoveryCDIHelper class at all.

I do not know whether this helps but this is the pom file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
<artifactId>movieplex7</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>movieplex7</name>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>java.net</id>
        <url>https://maven.java.net/content/groups/promoted/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0-b80</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-m13-2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>        
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.batch</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.batch-api-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-b10</version>        
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put the Java EE API dependency to the provided scope :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>7.0-b80</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

.jar is the default type. Put it in your pom.xml file only for other type like pom, war, and so on.