# CDI deployment failure:com/sun/enterprise/InjectionException

Tags: maven, jsf, jakarta-ee, cdi, glassfish-4

I've been trying to solve the Problem here: [Previous Deployment error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294165/weld-001318-cannot-resolve-an-ambiguous-dependency-between-in-glassfish-4) and I have reduced the application code to a minimum. 
I still have problem deploying the application to GlassFish 4.

Here the Server Log:

```
INFO:   WELD-000119 Not generating any bean definitions from com.sun.faces.vendor.Tomcat6InjectionProvider because of underlying class loading error: Type org.apache.AnnotationProcessor not found.  If this is unexpected, enable DEBUG logging to see the full error.
INFO:   WELD-000119 Not generating any bean definitions from com.sun.faces.vendor.Jetty6InjectionProvider because of underlying class loading error: Type Lorg.mortbay.jetty.plus.annotation.InjectionCollection; not found.  If this is unexpected, enable DEBUG logging to see the full error.
INFO:   WELD-000119 Not generating any bean definitions from com.sun.faces.vendor.GlassFishInjectionProvider because of underlying class loading error: Type com.sun.enterprise.InjectionException not found.  If this is unexpected, enable DEBUG logging to see the full error.
WARNING:   WELD-001519 An InjectionTarget implementation is created for an abstract class com.sun.faces.taglib.jsf_core.MaxMinValidatorTag. It will not be possible to produce instances of this type!
WARNING:   WELD-001529 An InjectionTarget implementation is created for a class javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentTag$UIComponentTagAdapter which does not have any appropriate constructor.
WARNING:   WELD-001519 An InjectionTarget implementation is created for an abstract class javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentBodyTag. It will not be possible to produce instances of this type!
WARNING:   WELD-001519 An InjectionTarget implementation is created for an abstract class javax.faces.webapp.ConverterELTag. It will not be possible to produce instances of this type!
WARNING:   WELD-001519 An InjectionTarget implementation is created for an abstract class javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentELTag. It will not be possible to produce instances of this type!
WARNING:   WELD-001519 An InjectionTarget implementation is created for an abstract class javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentClassicTagBase. It will not be possible to produce instances of this type!
WARNING:   WELD-001519 An InjectionTarget implementation is created for an abstract class javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentTag. It will not be possible to produce instances of this type!
WARNING:   WELD-001519 An InjectionTarget implementation is created for an abstract class javax.faces.webapp.UIComponentTagBase. It will not be possible to produce instances of this type!
WARNING:   WELD-001519 An InjectionTarget implementation is created for an abstract class javax.faces.webapp.ValidatorELTag. It will not be possible to produce instances of this type!
SEVERE:   Exception during lifecycle processing
org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: CDI deployment failure:com/sun/enterprise/InjectionException
    at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:225)
    at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:131)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:328)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:493)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
```

I have also pushed the application code to GutHub: [testfish1 code](https://github.com/kenparker/testfish1.git)

The Application consist of:

1. Template.xhtml
2. Index.xhtml
3. Movietest.java (Entity)
4. AbstractFacade.Java
5. MovieFacadeREST.Java

Pls. let me know if you wand the code posted here

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two dependencies that are not listed as provided.  One is javaee-api, and the other is javax.inject.  Here's a gist with an updated pom.xml for you: https://gist.github.com/johnament/11327517

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are providing (means it is packaged in your WAR file) a `javaee-api` version which is different to the one included in Glassfish 4. You are using a beta version, you shouldn't do that anyway.

Change your `pom.xml` to the final version like this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
```

Because it is included in Glassfish 4, you can even set the scope to `provided`. 
In addition to that you are including the package `javax.inject`, which is not needed in the packaged web application. You can set it's scope to `provided` too.

Comment: thanks I changed the POM.XML and it worked. Great :-)